# Memory Management in Xamarin Forms Project (Specifically Android)

Tags: performance, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, performance-testing

We have an android app which is developed in latest version of the Xamarin and used following major depenandacies/libraries

1. PRISM
2. REALM for Local Storage
3. Library for Reactive Programming (Using Observables)

When we are doing profiling, app is using around 600 MB of runtime memory which looks huge and it gets increased by the time. See attached memory utlization graph after 2 hours of profiling
[image]

We are trying to optimize it by idenitfying the piece of code from where there might be chance of memory leak or the places where objects are continusly used or the places where any background task is continusly running.

I have few questions :

1. Is it good to force the Garbage collector to run when app goes to background or Idle for few minutes? (got something on microsoft but not sure https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/internals/garbage-collection). Will this help to reduce the memory utilization? Or it will create issue by creating un fragmented memory spaces ?
2. In the graph, if you see it is showing large amount of memory being used by some "Others". IS there a way to know what contains this "Others" ?
3. Any other way to optimize the xamarin (C#) code which can manage the memory in the Mono Framework? (Ob course we are using IDisposble, using block extensively )
4. Any other way to optimize this to make sure less memory usase at run time?
5. We also tried Layout Compression and Fast renderers too for Controls Tree Structure optimization but still memory consumption is 500+ MB. Any other way to optimize the XAML code (have seen and implemented the guide provided by microsoft for Xmaarin layout optimization)
6. Is there any way or good tool for Perfromance testing of the Mobile app (apart from Profiling)?

Comment: Unfortunately, this is beyond the scope of StackOverflow. I wouldn't force GC in production, but its worth trying as a test. If it DOES NOT remove 100+ MB, then you'll know the problem is that stuff is being held on to, that shouldn't be; can't be fixed by GC nor by optimizations. Then the hard part is figuring out why. Search `mocking in unit testing`. If you mock the entire UI, you can exercise your other code to verify it is behaving well. If it is, then you need to isolate what UI class is staying around when it shouldn't. I don't know any easy way to get these answers.

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve Thanks for your suggestion. Let me see if I can do it.